# What is a “réponse de principe”?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

What is the difference between *réponse de principe* and *réponse*?

E.g.:

> Peux-tu s'il te plait nous donner ton adresse pour le faire-part ainsi qu'une **réponse de principe**?

vs.

> Peux-tu s'il te plait nous donner ton adresse pour le faire-part ainsi qu'une **réponse**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A “réponse de principe” is a non-definitive answer, i.e. what you would answer to the best of your knowledge right now. Let’s say for example group of friends are going to a beach house for a week in August. You meet the organiser at a party and he asks you if you think you’ll come. Of course, she can’t expect you to be able to give a definitive answer immediately: you’d have to check your agenda and possibly discuss it with your partner before accepting.

Thus she asks for a “réponse de principe”: you could say “I’ll probably come, but I still need to check the details. In the mean time, you can count me as a participant, I’ll give you my definitive answer in a few days.”